# systems administration using Packet Tracer

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer

Good day! Is it possible to do systems administration on packet tracer?
Ex. disabling a computer to access its hard drive.
If so, is testing also possible? 
Thank you!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, packet tracer is for simulating networks, not for simulating computers.